# Multicolinearity check (pertubation test) in Logistic Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am in learning phase of ML and i wanna know how  to check for multicolinearity in Logistoc Regression? with codes and explanantion and pre-requiste to check for it? or any link will also do what is dummies pls cover that too as i was watching youtube they all were discussing? please over from scratch if possible please ?